# Placement of "even" within phrase

Tags: grammar

Which one would sound better?

1. to the point where it may be considered a heirloom **even**.
2. to the point where it may **even** be considered a heirloom.

I think (2) is fairly standard in terms of structure, but for some reason I feel as though (1) is grammatically correct as well.

Comment: There would be a comma intonation between _heirloom_ and _even_ at the end in (1); it's pretty much restricted to ingroup speech. The more normal place would be after the first auxiliary verb, like (2)

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatical to have "even" at the end, though it's less common and more informal.  See [this usage guide from the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/even), which says:

> We sometimes put even at the end of a clause or sentence in informal speaking.
>
> Compare:
>
> - *I can’t remember him at all. I’ve even forgotten what he looks like*. (typical position)
> - *I can’t remember him at all. I’ve forgotten what he looks like even*. (more informal, used in speaking)